# How to use global variable in onCreate method of Android

Tags: java, android, oncreate

I am very much new to Android world. I was just trying to check how a global variable can be used in `onCreate()` method in Android, whenever i tried doing so, it closed abruptly. When I displayed some random text in the code, it was displayed successfully. 

Here's my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public static int num_i=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_beer);
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(num_i);
        num_i++;
    }
}
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: Ok, let's assume I am a magician, and can see the stacktraceof your exception. It tells you that resource with identifier <some identifier> not found. That happens because `TextView.setText()` has more than one overload. So `TextView.setText(int)`, which you are calling expects the String resource identifier as a parameter (`R.string.something` for example). If you want to show an int in the TextVIew, you first have to convert it to string.

Comment: Title in this question is completely misleading, can you please update the title of your question to reflect more on the `setText` with `int` parameter problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **[setText(CharSequence text)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)**

> Sets the text to be displayed. it takes String as a parameter not a number
>
> **Sample** : **`tv.setText("PREM");`**

- **[setText(int resid)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)**

> Sets the text to be displayed using a string resource identifier.
>
> **Sample** : **`tv.setText(R.string.app_name);`**

first you have to convert your **`int`** value in to a **`String`**

Try this use

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(num_i));
```

or

```
tv.setText(num_i+"");
```

instead of this

```
 tv.setText(num_i);
```

Comment: Also exists: `void setText (int resid)` which takes an int as parameter

Comment: i was just updating my thanks for your suggestion @pleft

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `tv.setText()` with a number as parameter. Try using `String.valueOf(num_i)`.

So in your case:
 `tv.setText(String.valueOf(num_i))` or `tv.setText(num_i + "");`